# How do I set the language of a variable in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, iso-639

I know how to set the language of a literal: `"foo"@en`

But what about `?foo@en` (which doesn't work)?

Context: I want to copy a bunch of labels set to `en-gb` into just `en` so they play better with the knowledge management tool I'm using. So something like this:

```
INSERT {
   ?subject skos:prefLabel ?object@en
} 

WHERE {
  ?subject skos:prefLabel ?object .
  FILTER (lang(?object) = "en-gb")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`str`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) allows you to get the lexical form of a language-tagged literal, and [`STRLANG`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strlang) allows you to specify the language tag of a literal.

```
CONSTRUCT { 
  ?subject skos:prefLabel ?label_en .
}

WHERE { 

  ?subject skos:prefLabel ?label_enGB . 
  FILTER (lang(?label_enGB) = "en-gb") .

  BIND( STRLANG(str(?label_enGB), "en") AS ?label_en ) .

}
```

Example:

1. `?label_enGB`: `"foo"@en-gb`
2. `str(?label_enGB)`: `"foo"`
3. `STRLANG(str(?label_enGB), "en")`: `"foo"@en`